# ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3, python 2.7 cannot load pickle file even dump with protocol = 2

Tags: python, pickle

I have used:
pickle.dump(data, f, protocol=2)

And try to open the pickle file with python 2.7, however, it still pop up with the error "ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3".

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example that we could test?

Comment: That sounds like you're just wrong about the protocol=2 thing. Maybe the pickle doesn't actually come from the code you think it does.

Comment: Note that a file can have more than one pickle in it. Maybe your file has multiple pickles in a mixture of protocols.

Comment: if you are using python 3 to pickle, on top of using protocol=2 make sure that you specify the encoding (idealy both during dump and load)

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely to be a pickle file created with python 3. I guess you mainly use python 2.7. Either you re-create the pickle file with python 2.7 or you use python 3.